# Listing available smb shares on a network through the command line in linux

Tags: samba, fedora, server-message-block

I was wondering if there is a way of listing all the smb servers on a local network (like looking at a network neighborhood in windows) via the command line in fedora.

Comment: What do you mean with 'smb servers'? Do you mean **Samba** servers, or do you mean all file servers (wether Samba or Windows, wether in my own or in other workgroups/domains) which speak the SMB protocol?

Comment: Also, your question's title (mentioning 'smb shares') somewhat contradicts its text (mentioning 'smb servers'). Which one did you mean?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This command is a very little known secret of Samba. It returns IP adresses of all *Samba* servers in one's own broadcast domain:

`nmblookup __SAMBA__`

This one returns a list of all NetBIOS names and their aliases of all Samba servers in the neighbourhood (it does a *'node status query'*):

`nmblookup -S __SAMBA__`

This one returns a list of all IP adresses of *SMB* servers (that is, Linux+Unix/Samba or Windows) in the neighbourhood:

`nmblookup '*'`

Finally, all NetBIOS names and their aliases of all SMB servers (Linux+Unix/Samba or Windows):

`nmblookup -S '*'`

---

The command given in the other answer `nmblookup -S WORKGROUP` does ***NOT*** return all Samba or all SMB servers from the neighbourhood. Instead, it returns all servers' NetBIOS names *who happen to be members of a workgroup named 'WORKGROUP'*. The results are independent of the servers' OS (wether that is Windows, or wether that is Linux/Samba) -- and it is a well known fact that sometimes lots of Windows member server are part of a Samba-controlled domain or workgroup. [Yes, it happens that Samba's default workgroup name is 'WORKGROUP'... but so what??]. -- But the question was *'How do I get to know all SMB (Samba?!?) servers in my network neighbourhood?'*

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Interestingly using these suggestions I only see the Samba share on the server I'm currently on. To really detect another Samba server (it has WORKGROUP workgroup), I had to run `nmblookup -S WORKGROUP`.. not sure how to really list any server since `nmblookup -S '*'` and other commands only returned the local server as mentioned above.

Comment: For me also, the other answer worked better, though not correct. `nmblookup -S '*'` returns only the local server. more information might be needed... __SAMBA__ only returns samba servers, while I'd all like all SMB share (windows included). At least I found the window share which were part of WORKGROUP. I'm not sure why all the fuss about samba/smbd, and why this answer would get the points.

Comment: @Fred: The answer says explicitly (not clearly enough?!?) that (1) with **`__SAMBA__`** you get the *Samba* servers, and (2) with **`'*'`** you get *all SMB* servers. This answer gets points because it is the correct one.

Comment: I only say this is not working on my computer. I'm using ubuntu 16.04, nmblookup from package samba-common-bin 2:4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1. Maybe there is something wrong with my environment. Or regression in the tools, it's been a long time this question was answered. The previous comment suggests I'm not alone seeing this behaviour.

Comment: It does not work in Samba 4.x anymore.

Comment: It works fine for me with Samba 4 (Ubuntu 22.04), but there are some changes, it lists IPs and not names, I had to add `-T` option to see names.

Comment: I get `Can't load /etc/samba/smb.conf` - do I need a configuration just to do lookups? After touching the file I still find nothing.

Answer (score 15):

```
nmblookup -S WORKGROUP
```

from the: https://web.archive.org/web/20101121043732/http://brneurosci.org/linuxsetup38b.html

Comment: You might need to tweak the firewall settings on a default install.

Comment: I'll downvote this answer. -- I can't believe such a ***WRONG*** answer gets 2 upvotes. The given command only lists servers which are members of a workgroup named "workgroup". And it lists them regardless of OS (Samba/Linux or not, Windows or not). The question was about getting to know all ***SAMBA*** servers on the local network (regardless of workgroup name).

Comment: Actually, he didn't say he was looking for all samba servers.  He said "all the smb servers".  I suppose I failed to elaborate to the degree that you did, in that you can search for wildcard workgroups--but really, I made it clear that I was referencing the manual, and I got the OP what he needed.  Not to mention, I answered half a month before you did--I don't understand what you're so bent out of shape about.

Comment: I get `Can't load /etc/samba/smb.conf` - do I need a configuration just to do lookups?

Answer (score 12):

On my network - as of this writing (things do change) - smbtree is my preferred solution. It asks for your password (meaning your Samba password), and then it gives a nicely detailed list that includes netbios name, available shares, and the share description.

nmblookup, on the other hand, does not list all the available shares on my network. I do not know why it does not, but it doesn't.

From the smbtree man page:

> smbtree is a smb browser program in text mode. It is similar to the
>   "Network Neighborhood" found on Windows computers. It prints a tree
>   with all the known domains, the servers in those domains and the
>   shares on the servers.

The nmblookup command does have more switches and options. The nmblookup man page: [nmblookup man page](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/nmblookup.1.html)

Noted for posterity - as these answers do stick around - and as I said, I find that smbtree would be a better answer to the OP on my network.

Comment: The output of smbtree is great! - Wish it didn't ask for my PWD when im logged in a root tho, never seen that before!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Try `smbtree -N` if you are looking at services that don't need passwords.

Comment: I understand, it wanted the SMB password not my root password, they were likely the same, but yes i have my shares restricted to non dhcp IP address pool, but no password

Comment: `nmblookup` finds three shares on my network, `smbtree` finds nothing :/

Answer (score 8):

In samba version 4, `nmblookup '*'` no longer works; it only gives the local server.  It used to work in samba version 3.

Now, you have to use `nmblookup WORKGROUP`, which as Kurt mentioned, only returns servers in workgroup `WORKGROUP`.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this is via Avahi (Bonjour), as long as the servers are publishing:

```
avahi-browse -r _smb._tcp
```

Answer (score 6):

a better way, more fiendly printed, is to use smbtree.

```
$ smbtree
Enter user01's password: DOMAIN_A
        \\FREEBOX_SERVER                Freebox Server
                \\FREEBOX_SERVER\IPC$                   IPC Service (Freebox Server)
                \\FREEBOX_SERVER\Disque dur             AutoShare of fbxhdiskd partition 2
```

Comment: @Corvus-B had already suggested `smbtree` in an answer long before.